# Show/Hide password button not working when input is active in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3, passwords, show-hide

I am trying to implement the show/hide button for the password field in Ionic 3. I have got the code help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815831/how-to-create-login-in-ionic-2-with-show-hide-password)

login.html

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input [type]="passwordType" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon item-end [name]="passwordIcon" class="passwordIcon" (click)='hideShowPassword()'></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
```

login.scss

```
    .passwordIcon{
        font-size: 1.3em;
        position: absolute;
        right: .1em;
        top: .5em;
        z-index: 2;
     }
```

login.ts

```
passwordType: string = 'password';
passwordIcon: string = 'eye-off';
  hideShowPassword() {
    this.passwordType = this.passwordType === 'text' ? 'password' : 'text';
    this.passwordIcon = this.passwordIcon === 'eye-off' ? 'eye' : 'eye-off';
}
```

I have done one modification in the .scss file and made the icon absolute so that it appears on top of the input field instead of the side.
This icon click is working when the Input field is not active/selected but if I am in the middle of typing in the Input Field, the click is not working/recognized. Please help.

With the solution suggested my field looks like this.
[image]

Comment: Maybe your icon is too small to be reached by you finger (it happened sometimes for me)
Try to add a log inside the ```hideShowPassword()``` to see if the click is working

Comment: And also, you are working with Ionic 3, I am used to use ```(tap)``` instead of ```(click)```, maybe it can help.

Comment: Sorry but that's not the issue. As I have mentioned, the click is working fine when the input field is not active/selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what

> ... and made the icon absolute so that it appears on top of the input field instead of the side

would mean, but still, using `position: absolute` on top of inputs may lead to bugs specially on iOS.

Another possible issue of your code is that buttons are designed to handle issues related with taps in mobile devices, but icons may not work properly sometimes.

---

Anyway, please take a look at **[this working Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-password-button)** to do something like this:

[image]

The code is quite simple actually - the idea is to use a button with an icon instead of just an icon to avoid issues with the tap event:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public showPassword: boolean = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  public onPasswordToggle(): void {
    this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;
  }

}
```

**Template**

```
<ion-header>
  <!-- ... -->
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <!-- ... -->

  <ion-item>
    <ion-input placeholder="Password" [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" clearOnEdit="false"></ion-input>
    <button (click)="onPasswordToggle()" ion-button clear small item-end icon-only>
      <ion-icon [name]="showPassword ? 'eye-off' : 'eye'"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, one way to keep the button inside of the border would be not to apply the border to the `input`, but to the `ion-item`.

Something like this for example:

```
ion-item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

would result in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the reason I went for an absolute icon is that the style of my input. It has borders and with this solution, my icons come out of the border. Please check my screenshot. Is there a way to following this approach to bring it inside?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TapasMukherjee. I've updated the answer - do you think that applying the border to the `ion-item` could be a way to solve this in the context of your app's UI/UX?

Comment: <ion-item lines="none" style="border: 2px solid #000;">
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="password"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>