# ion-input with icon at the end

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

```
    <ion-input placeholder="Username" formControlName="userName" class="primary-input"></ion-input>
     
         <ion-input [type]="passwordType" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" autocomplete="off"  class="primary-input"> 
        <ion-icon name="eye"  (click)="togglePasswordMode()"  ></ion-icon>
        </ion-input>
  <div class="ion-margin-top">
    <ion-button expand="block" (click)="!isSubmitted && login()" >LOGIN</ion-button>
  </div>
       
 The above is my code currenty showing like this
```

[image]

currently showing icon at the start but i need to show at the end ..

**i tried  ion-item with slot="end" works but i dont  want  use that  beacuse textbox show slightly right side ..I need some alternative solution without using ion-item..**

I am using ionic 5 ..Please some one help to css
EDIT:

```
.primary-input {
    background: aliceblue;
    color: #999999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

EDIT:
This is the output of ion-item

[image]

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815831/how-to-create-login-in-ionic-2-with-show-hide-password

Comment: Thanks but not woks for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually we use the icon in a button separately from the `ion-input` field. So you can use a border on the `ion-item` as the example.

HTM file:

```
      <form #loginForm="ngForm" class="access" (submit)="login(model)">
        <ion-list lines="none">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">EMAIL</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">PASSWORD</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" name="psw" [(ngModel)]="model.psw"></ion-input>
            <ion-button slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="showPassword()" class="seeClient">
              <ion-icon *ngIf="showPsw==true" name="eye-outline" color="warning" class="iconEye"></ion-icon>
              <ion-icon *ngIf="showPsw==false" name="eye-off-outline" color="warning" class="iconEye"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-button [disabled]="!mobile" expand="block" type="submit" color="warning">Entrar</ion-button>
      </form>
```

SCSS file:

```
.iconEye {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ion-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #eac402;
    --highlight-height: 0px;
    --highlight-color-valid: #eac402;
    --highlight-color-focused: #eac402;
    --highlight-color-invalid: #eac402;
}
```

[image: Login image input using icon button]

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code with an `ion-item`, place the `ion-icon` outside the `ion-input`, it would go something like this:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input [type]="passwordType" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" autocomplete="off" class="primary-input"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon name="eye" (click)="togglePasswordMode()"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
```

Here's how it would look like now:

[image: demo]

## EDIT:

To fix previous behavior for multiple inputs, I would suggest using `ion-grid`, `ion-row`, `ion-col` layout components.

Here's the code

```
<ion-grid class="m-0">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-input placeholder="Username" formControlName="userName" class="primary-input"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-input [type]="passwordType" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" autocomplete="off" class="primary-input"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-icon name="eye" class="m-auto" (click)="togglePasswordMode()"></ion-icon>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

And here's how it would look like now

[image]
Hope this helped.

Comment: i know this ..i hve issue attached in question..But text box showing small if i put ion-item..How to do both ion-item look similar

Comment: @Glen - I have just updated my answer, I tried to look for simpler approach but I didn't find one.

Comment: Thanks for ur time..i need text icon inside textbox

Answer (score 1):

Add **flex-direction: row-reverse** to `ion-input` style

```
<ion-input type="email" style="flex-direction:row-reverse;">
   <ion-icon name="logo-ionic"></ion-icon>
</ion-input>
```